# my node and npm are already latest version

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, npm, gulp

as u can see i am facing the error in 3rd line ,i  did
sudo npm install gulp
ubuntu@ip-172-31-84-181:~/socialsite$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
before showing this error it was unable to find gulp related modules like sass , rev , undertaker etc so i installed them individually to get rid of them but now i am getting this error
i tried to upadte my node nd npm but it shows they are of latest version
i also tried to rm rf node_modules but it also did not work
ubuntu@ip-172-31-84-181:~/socialsite$ node -v
v8.10.0
ubuntu@ip-172-31-84-181:~/socialsite$ npm -v
3.5.2

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-84-181:~/socialsite$ gulp build
/home/ubuntu/socialsite/node_modules/globby/index.js:28
        } catch {
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/ubuntu/socialsite/node_modules/del/index.js:4:16)
```

Comment: the thing that this code is inside node_modules in am unable to catch the error according to me the code in given file looks fine, could you please be bit more specific about the solution to this as this is my first deployment.

Answer (score -1):

Running the `npm rebuild` command might help resolve the issue

Comment: no it did not resolve, still facing same issue

Comment: I understand that you really want an answer that brings a solution, we are here spending time sharing actions so that, with luck, it brings some solution, however just because it didn't solve the problem I don't see why voting negative on the answers... How do you want people to help that way?

Answer (score -1):

updating node version from 8.0.0 to 14.0.0 made it fine